# EF and database sharding

Tags: entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-6, sharding

I decided to shard my SQL Azure Database, does that mean that EF will no longer be able to help me? in the end, should I continue to use EF or should i start building my own queries?

Comment: What database engine?

Comment: Sorry... Check my edited... Sql Azure Basic

Comment: Sure, EF works fine - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj556244#federations

Comment: @EkoostikMartin no longer... its being phased out...

Comment: What is being phased out exactly?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Federations

Comment: Are you doing custom sharding to go around the issue with retired federations?

Comment: @Igorek Yes i am... any ideas?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540901/entity-framework-and-sharded-database